# When to use "Me" and "I" in comparative sentences?

Tags: pronouns

> He is taller than me/I?

Also, what is the difference between the two:

> 1 - I love you better than him.
>
> 2 - I love you better than he.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23632/tom-is-taller-than-i/23633#23633 and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/not-i-or-not-me/14575#14575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form that would make sense in the first part of the sentence. You would use "I am taller", not "Me am taller", so

> He is taller than I [am tall].

In the second case, the distinction is

> I love you better than [I love] him.

(That is, you are saying who you love better.)

vs

> I love you better than he [loves you].

(You are saying who loves the listener better.)

Comment: While this is technically correct, native speakers commonly use me/him rather than I/he. In fact, saying "taller than I" and "better than he" sound quite old fashioned to me.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with this answer. Using object pronouns me, him, her, them is correct in these cases, and much more common than the subjective pronouns that this answer suggests.

Comment: @laugh It depends on the dialect. My answer describes standard English used, for example, in formal writing. Spoken English often does use the object pronouns in either case, leaving the intended meaning to be determined by context.

Answer (score 0):

(My original answer was somewhat biased towards my own preference. Edited to reflect the bigger picture).

There is a debate about which one is *correct*, but in practice both are in use. "He is taller than me" is somewhat more common in casual writing and speech. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative.

A probably undisputed alternative is "he is taller than I am". In this case "I am" is an object clause, in which "I" is the subject, so it takes the subjective form.

Regarding the two forms of "I love you better": there could be two meanings as the other answer suggests. I will use "more than" instead of "better than", since it is more common:

> I love you more than him

Means "more than I love him".

> I love you more than he does

Means "more than he loves you".

"More than he" vs. "more than him" is a big debate among language enthusiasts. For a long discussion on this topic, see http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/than-i-versus-than-me?page=1